# what is wrong with my maven-3.1.1 and nexus-2.6.4-02 when this exception happend?

Tags: java, maven, exception, nexus

I am running maven with nexus on my computer,but when I run command `mvn help:system`, I get this exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:system (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:system failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:jar:2.2 -> org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-tools-api:jar:2.4.3: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-tools-api:jar:2.4.3: Failure to find org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:8 in `http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public` was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of roger-nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:system (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:system failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:jar:2.2 -> org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-tools-api:jar:2.4.3
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:system failed: Pluginorg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies couldnot be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:jar:2.2 -> org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-tools-api:jar:2.4.3
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:87)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:jar:2.2 -> org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-tools-api:jar:2.4.3
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:204)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.createPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:357)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.setupPluginRealm(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:325)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getPluginRealm(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:83)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:jar:2.2 ->org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-tools-api:jar:2.4.3
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:292)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:317)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:192)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed toread artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-tools-ap
i:jar:2.4.3
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:370)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:461)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:261)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Failure to find org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:8 in `http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public` was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of roger-nexus has elapsed or updates are for
ced
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:126)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:817)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:669)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:361)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:8 in `http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public` was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of roger-nexus has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:122)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:8 in `http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public` was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of roger-nexus has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:232)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:599)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:518)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:436)
        ... 36 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] `http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException`
```

I guess the problem is my network components block access to some file.But the confusing thing is that I can run maven normally without nexus, so I also suspect my setting.xml is wrong, here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>D:/DeveloperKit/maven_repos</localRepository>
  <pluginGroups>
  </pluginGroups>

  <proxies>
  </proxies>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>roger-nexus</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>
     <mirror>
      <id>roger-nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>Mirror of roger</name>
      <url>http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>jdk-1.7</id>
      <activation>
        <jdk>1.7</jdk>
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>jdk17</id>
          <name>Repository for JDK 1.7 builds</name>
          <url>http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>jdk-1.7</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

A default setup for using [nexus is like the following](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html):

```xml
<settings
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
 <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Apart from that based on the error message:

```
Failure to find org.apache.maven:maven-parent:pom:8 in
`http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public` was cached in the local repository,
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of roger-nexus has 
elapsed or updates are forced ->
```

It's caused by that you don't specify the update policy for other repository. May be your connection to Maven Central etc. has timed out (via Nexus).

The best is to drop your local repository and retry it. If that happens again check the configuration in Nexus if you have changed some of the defaults.